# Unity player moves opposite direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Well I am currenty programming a 2D game in Unity. I have a Player which you can rotate to the left or to the right with the arrow keys. If you press the right arrow key the player should rotate right and if you press left arrow key the player should rotate to the left. Right now if the player press left arrow key it rotates right and if right is pressed it rotates to the left. This is my Code:

```
private void RotatePlayer()
{  
   float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
   float rotation = horizontal * speed;
   transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * rotation);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just invert the input:

`float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * -1;`

Also - have you seen the new input system?
https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/QuickStartGuide.html